# Seeking list of residential buildings (API / DB) for USA

Tags: usa, openstreetmap, address

I'm developing an app where the user will choose some area on the map and then obtain list of residential buildings addresses belongs to it.
For now I think about this flow: get bounding box coordinates of selected area -> get list of streets (using OSM) of the area -> get list of buildings for each street (using Zillow) -> check is building coordinates belong to selected area.

Maybe there is any downloadable DB of all residential buildings of USA or one-solution API where I could get all buildings by single request?

Answer (score 3):

Why not use OSM Buildings data?
Microsoft released [US Building Footprints dataset](https://github.com/Microsoft/USBuildingFootprints) but you are going to want to ensure accuracy. I've read/seen examples where it is not 100% accurate.

### OSM Buildings References:

- [OSM Wiki](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Buildings)
- [Fetching Building Data with OSM](https://github.com/inasafe/inasafe/wiki/Fetching-Building-Data-with-OSM)
- [Extracting Building Footprints from OpenStreetMap](https://github.com/tudelft3d/3dfier/wiki/Extracting-building-footprints-from-OpenStreetMap)
- [How to Download OSM 3D Building Data](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/207960/how-to-download-osm-3d-building-data)

Comment: thank you @albert. do you mean https://osmbuildings.org/documentation/ ?

Comment: that is osm buildings, but if i am not mistaken, doesn't osm offer buildings data in general?

Comment: I don't know, but even OSM website don't show any buildings
https://gyazo.com/bc0ce01b10e7eb0ac2f7efec607ba2c3
also I need determine it is private (signle-family building) or not

Comment: how to get OSM buildings data? when I user OSM API, it returns only nodes and ways (streets)?

Comment: OSM is a project based on volunteers. Building data hasn't been added yet for every location. Feel free to join OSM and improve it yourself.